# How can I implement phone caller in Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to create a method where I can call a certain user with a custom UI which does not display the user's phone number, but, instead it displays his name or a random String. There is a way to achieve that in Flutter? Also, I want to hide the number on recents calls from the phone' OS. Thank You!

Comment: It'd be best if you call inApp as it has nothing to do with the phone recent calls. Please do the necessary research for 3rd party service providers that facilates voice call through them. There exists privacy concerns but the best we could do is trust them

Comment: So you are telling me that if I want to call someone using the Flutter App that behaves exactly like Whatsapp's calling I have to find a 3rd party services providers and if I want to implement just a normal call I can use a simple package that behaves in a simple way?

Comment: but if you use package from pub.dev , the number of  recipient will be in the phone's OS right. please go through this https://medium.flutterdevs.com/implementing-phone-calls-using-the-flutter-app-e350ea275c92